# Why is the Same JAR Repeated Multiple Times in My Run Configuration's Source Lookup Path Section?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" (Version: `2022-06 (4.24.0)`) installed on my Windows 10 PC. I have a basic Hello World Java Project called test that runs fine, but when I open its `Java Application` Run Configuration and click on the `Source` tab, it lists the jar `jrt-fs.jar` from the default JRE as being in the `Source Lookup Path` 49 times:

[Screenshot of Eclipse Source Lookup Path for Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3yvu.png)

[Screenshot of `test` project's *Projects* tab under *Properties: Java Build Path*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyV7O.png)

`test` project's `.classpath` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-17">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Why is this listed so many times? I'm worried it will causes problems down the road.

Comment: It seems the project `test` depends on itself. What do you have in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ in the tab _Projects_? Could you please also include the content of your project's `.classpath` file in your question?

Comment: @howlger edited question to include the requested information - there doesn't seem to be anything specified for the Modulepath or Classpath in the *Projects* tab.

Comment: @howlger On your end, you don't see multiple jrt-fs.jar entries?

Comment: @levantpied No. Do you see this in the current Eclipse IDE 2023-06?

Comment: @howlger Interesting. Yeah, I see this in `Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0), Build id: 20230608-1333`.

Comment: @levantpied What are you mean by _this_? Is _this_ for all projects and installed JREs? Are nested projects involved? If yes, how? Are there project dependencies (via `.classpath` or `.project` files or file system links)? Are there additional installed plugins or is it reproducible with the Eclipse SDK? What do you and Joshua Lusk have in common?

Comment: Maybe related to the commit https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.debug.git/commit/?id=ef4f1d7991058e65d74ccfcc00ad7081f9429986 and issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490103